# Incorrect syntax for Parameters.Add

Tags: c#, sql-server

Trying to insert static value to the database. However I get an error when I try to compile the code

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>   Additional information: Incorrect syntax near '@lname'.

This is my code:

```
    private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString);


       SqlCommand query = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tbl_users (fname, mname, lname) VALUES ('@fname', '@mname', '@lname'", con);

        query.Parameters.Add("@fname", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = "Mark Dhem";
        query.Parameters.Add("@mname", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = "Subito";
        query.Parameters.Add("@lname", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = "Mansueto";

        con.Open();
        query.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

    }
```

Comment: You don't need single quote with your parameters, it should be like this: `(@fname, @mname, @lname", con)`

Comment: This is also missing a bracket

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the single quotes. While I'm here, the connection should be inside a `using` block, to ensure it is still closed if an exception is thrown.

```
private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var con = new SqlConnection(conString))
    using (var query = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tbl_users (fname, mname, lname) VALUES (@fname, @mname, @lname)", con))
    {
        query.Parameters.Add("@fname", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = "Mark Dhem";
        query.Parameters.Add("@mname", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = "Subito";
        query.Parameters.Add("@lname", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = "Mansueto";

        con.Open();
        query.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

But neither of those are why you saw an error. `'@lname'` is still a valid string literal, even if it wouldn't do what you wanted. The problem was a missing closing parentheses at the end of the statement.